# Numero de elementos de un ListView en un TextView

Tags: android-studio, listview, textview

Actualizo el código al que tengo ahora:

```
public class ArrayAdapterWithCountingFilter extends AppCompatActivity implements Filter.FilterListener {

ListView lvElements;
TextView tvTotals;
EditText etSearch;
StringFilterCountArrayAdapter adapter;
Filter.FilterListener listener;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_arrayadapter);



    String tokens[] =
            {"Constitución Española",
                    "Ley Orgánica 10/1995, de 23 de noviembre, del Código Penal",
                    "Real Decreto de 14 de septiembre de 1882 por el que se aprueba la Ley de Enjuiciamiento Criminal",
                    "Ley Orgánica 4/2015, de 30 de marzo, de protección de la seguridad ciudadana",
                    "Ley Orgánica 4/2000, de 11 de enero, sobre derechos y libertades de los extranjeros en España y su integración social",

            };

    lvElements = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvElements);
    tvTotals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotals);
    etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);



    etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            ArrayAdapterWithCountingFilter.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
        }
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {  }
    });

    List data = new ArrayList();
    data.addAll(Arrays.asList(tokens));
    adapter = new StringFilterCountArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_text_item, R.id.tvLisTextItem,data );

    lvElements.setAdapter(adapter);
    onFilterComplete(data.size()); //El parámetro no se usa pero ya que estamos pasémoslo bien



}

@Override
public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
    String totalsText = String.format("%d/%d", adapter.getFilteredCount(), adapter.getTotalCount());
    tvTotals.setText(totalsText);

}


public static class StringFilterCountArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    private int filteredCount = getCount ();
    private List<String> objects;
    private List<String> origObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    private Filter.FilterListener callbackListener;


    public StringFilterCountArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        this.objects = objects;
        origObjects.addAll(objects);
        this.callbackListener = (Filter.FilterListener) context;
    }


    public int getFilteredCount() {
        return filteredCount;
    }

    public int getTotalCount(){
        return origObjects.size();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter(){

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint == null || constraint.toString().trim().length() == 0){
                    filterResults.values = origObjects;
                }else{
                    List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(String s : origObjects){
                        if(s.contains(constraint)){
                            filtered.add(s);
                        }
                    }

                    filterResults.values = filtered;
                    filterResults.count = filtered.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                objects.clear();
                objects.addAll((List<String>) results.values);
                filteredCount = results.count;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                callbackListener.onFilterComplete(filteredCount);
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Juan, mis conocimientos son muy limitados y me pierdo con tu respuesta. He probado con respuestas a preguntas similares de otros usuarios y no he sido capaz como es normal. ¿Que lineas de código debería añadir?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para implementar un Filter que además cuente los resultados tenés que extender `ArrayAdapter<String>`, hacer un `@override` de `getFilter()` para que devuleva un Filter que además de filtrar, cuente los elementos y deje la cuenta en un nuevo attributo '`filteredCount`' que puedas recuperar con un `getFilteredCount()`.

Algunos detalles de implementación:

Como el filtrado requiere quitar y volver a agregar elementos a la lista que se muestra, la lista original con todos los elementos se restuarda en una lista aparte al crear el adaptador.

El funcionamiento del `Filter` es asincrónico, por lo tanto, necesitamos poder avisar al activity en este caso, cuando el filtro terminó de filtrar. Para eso implementamos un `callback` utilizando la interface `Filter.FilterListener`. Para este ejemplo hice que el activity lo implemente, pero también se podría haber implementado como un objecto más, sólo que en ese caso habría que pasarlo al contstructor del adapter en un argumento adicional.

Al contstruir el adapter cambié el `array` por un `List` dado que el array me trajo algunos problemas para poder eliminar los elementos existentes y reemplazarlos por los filtrados.

Por comodidad la clase `StringFilterCountArrayAdapter` en el código está como clase estática pero podría ser una clase aparte.

**ArrayAdapterWithCountingFilter Activity**

```
public class ArrayAdapterWithCountingFilter extends AppCompatActivity implements Filter.FilterListener {

    ListView lvElements;
    TextView tvTotals;
    EditText etSearch;
    StringFilterCountArrayAdapter adapter;
    Filter.FilterListener listener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_arrayadapter);

        String tokens[] =
                {"Constitución Española",
                        "Ley Orgánica 10/1995, de 23 de noviembre, del Código Penal",
                        "Real Decreto de 14 de septiembre de 1882 por el que se aprueba la Ley de Enjuiciamiento Criminal",
                        "Ley Orgánica 4/2015, de 30 de marzo, de protección de la seguridad ciudadana",
                        "Ley Orgánica 4/2000, de 11 de enero, sobre derechos y libertades de los extranjeros en España y su integración social",

                };

        lvElements = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvElements);
        tvTotals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotals);
        etSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSearch);

        etSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                ArrayAdapterWithCountingFilter.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {        }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {  }
        });

        List data = new ArrayList();
        data.addAll(Arrays.asList(tokens));
        adapter = new StringFilterCountArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.list_text_item, R.id.tvLisTextItem,data );

        lvElements.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Inicializa el TextView con la cantidad de filtrados.
        onFilterComplete(data.size()); //El parámetro no se usa pero ya que estamos pasémoslo bien
    }

    @Override
    public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
        int cantFiltrados = adapter.getFilteredCount();
        int cantTotal = adapter.getTotalCount();

        String totalsText = String.format("Mostrando: %d/%d", cantFiltrados, cantTotal);
        tvTotals.setText(totalsText);
    }


    public static class StringFilterCountArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        private int filteredCount = 0;
        private List<String> objects;
        private List<String> origObjects = new ArrayList<>();
        private Filter.FilterListener callbackListener;

        public StringFilterCountArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.objects = objects;
            origObjects.addAll(objects);
            // Setear la cantidad de filtrados inicial, que es el total de elementos de la lista
            this.filteredCount = origObjects.size();
            this.callbackListener = (Filter.FilterListener) context;
        }


        public int getFilteredCount() {
            return filteredCount;
        }

        public int getTotalCount(){
            return origObjects.size();
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter filter = new Filter(){

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if(constraint == null || constraint.toString().trim().length() == 0){
                        filterResults.values = origObjects;
                        // Si no hay registros filtrados volver a setear la cantidad de filtrados al total de la lista.
                        filterResults.count = origObjects.size();
                    }else{
                        List<String> filtered = new ArrayList<>();
                        for(String s : origObjects){
                            if(s.contains(constraint)){
                                filtered.add(s);
                            }
                        }

                        filterResults.values = filtered;
                        filterResults.count = filtered.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    objects.clear();
                    objects.addAll((List<String>) results.values);
                    filteredCount = results.count;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                    callbackListener.onFilterComplete(filteredCount);
                }
            };
            return filter;
        }
    }
}
```

**list_text_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLisTextItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_array_adapter.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvElements"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="8">
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTotals"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Esto me sale en la consola. E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: es.preguntalistview, PID: 8046
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{es.preguntalistview/es.preguntalistview.ArrayAdapterWithCountingFilter}: java.lang.ClassCastException: es.preguntalistview.ArrayAdapterWithCountingFilter cannot be cast to android.widget.Filter$FilterListener

Comment: Tienes razón!!! No copié esa linea y no me di cuenta que extendía. Voy haber si avanzo en esta dirección muchas gracias!!.

Comment: Tienes razón, el caso es que cuando carga los valores es 0/5 cuando la lista esta filtrada los valores son correctos y cuando borro los datos del editext el valor vuelve a 0/5. Como hago para que el valor sea 5/5?

Comment: El código lo tengo localizado pero no sé que cambiar o añadir para que el conteo inicial sea 5/5.

Comment: En public StringFilterCountArrayAdapter, this.filteredCount = origObjects.size(); Y en protected void onCreate, al final, o por lo menos después de crear el adapter, onFilterComplete(data.size());

Comment: Lo que me dices En public StringFilterCountArrayAdapter da error de sintaxis. He modificado    private int filteredCount = 0; por    private int filteredCount = getCount (); y ahora carga correctamente mostrando el editex5/5, pero despues de filtar al borrar los datos del editex el resultado es 0/5 en vez de volver al 5/5

Comment: He modificado la pregunta para que veas como esta el codigo

Comment: Fijate por favor donde esta esto en el codigo: // Setear la cantidad de filtrados inicial, que es el total de elementos de la lista
            this.filteredCount = origObjects.size();

Comment: Asi tengo el metodo y cuando borro se pone a 0/5. public StringFilterCountArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
            this.objects = objects;
            origObjects.addAll(objects);
            this.filteredCount = origObjects.size();
            this.callbackListener = (Filter.FilterListener) context;
        }

Comment: // Si no hay registros filtrados volver a setear la cantidad de filtrados al total de la lista.
                        filterResults.count = origObjects.size();

Comment: Perdona mi ignorancia pero no me entero.